# Деепричастный оборот + наречие

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот

Правильно ли расположены запятые? Почему-то глаза режет.

> Я стал предельно аккуратно и, стараясь не поднимать шума, рыться в
>   шкафчиках.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Деепричастный оборот не обособляется:

**Я стал предельно аккуратно и стараясь не поднимать шума рыться в шкафчиках.**

**Пояснение**

Розенталь ([ДЕЕПРИЧАСТНЫЕ КОНСТРУКЦИИ](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113#pp113)):

> Примечание. Одиночное деепричастие или деепричастный оборот не обособляется:
>   6) если деепричастный оборот или одиночное деепричастие выступает в качестве **однородного члена предложения** с необособленным обстоятельством: **Алёша длинно и как-то прищурив глаза посмотрел на Ракитина (Дост.);**